# docker: how to restart containers from files from /var/lib/docker/containers

Tags: docker

I have updated my distro from 13.04 to 13.10 and had a bunch of running containers. the container files are still in `/var/lib/docker/container` however I can not start these:

```
$ sudo docker start 7ef2b26aa60d70d9167571dcc55502eee0c9f80ad7601bacc8a047ca1b28be65
Error: No such container: 7ef2b26aa60d70d9167571dcc55502eee0c9f80ad7601bacc8a047ca1b28be65
2014/03/25 05:18:14 Error: failed to start one or more containers


$ sudo tail /var/log/upstart/docker.log
2014/03/25 05:11:19 POST /v1.10/images/create?fromImage=7ef2b26aa60d70d9167571dcc55502eee0c9f80ad7601bacc8a047ca1b28be65&tag=
[/var/lib/docker|5227412d] +job pull(7ef2b26aa60d70d9167571dcc55502eee0c9f80ad7601bacc8a047ca1b28be65, )
HTTP code: 404
[/var/lib/docker|5227412d] -job pull(7ef2b26aa60d70d9167571dcc55502eee0c9f80ad7601bacc8a047ca1b28be65, ) = ERR (1)
2014/03/25 05:18:14 POST /v1.10/containers/7ef2b26aa60d70d9167571dcc55502eee0c9f80ad7601bacc8a047ca1b28be65/start
[/var/lib/docker|5227412d] +job start(7ef2b26aa60d70d9167571dcc55502eee0c9f80ad7601bacc8a047ca1b28be65)
No such container: 7ef2b26aa60d70d9167571dcc55502eee0c9f80ad7601bacc8a047ca1b28be65
[/var/lib/docker|5227412d] -job start(7ef2b26aa60d70d9167571dcc55502eee0c9f80ad7601bacc8a047ca1b28be65) = ERR (1)
[error] server.go:950 Error: No such container: 7ef2b26aa60d70d9167571dcc55502eee0c9f80ad7601bacc8a047ca1b28be65
[error] server.go:85 HTTP Error: statusCode=404 No such container: 7ef2b26aa60d70d9167571dcc55502eee0c9f80ad7601bacc8a047ca1b28be65
```

debug log from docker startup

```
[debug] runtime.go:300 Cannot load container 7ef2b26aa60d70d9167571dcc55502eee0c9f80ad7601bacc8a047ca1b28be65 because it was created with another graph driver.
```

inspecting driver which this container was created with:

```
$ cd /var/lib/docker/containers/7ef2b26aa60d70d9167571dcc55502eee0c9f80ad7601bacc8a047ca1b28be65
$ cat ./config.json | grep -o Driver.*\",
Driver":"aufs","ExecDriver":"lxc-0.9.0",
```

is there any way to recover these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out after updating aufs was uninstalled. reinstalling like so:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-`uname -r`
```

fixes issue!