# Docker shows no containers or images after system reboot

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Help! I can't get docker to recognize the images and containers it had just a moment ago. After running `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` and rebooting, I see docker reporting no data:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
```

But the data appears to still be there

```
$ sudo du -hs /var/lib/docker/*
8.0K    /var/lib/docker/apparmor
1.9G    /var/lib/docker/aufs
136K    /var/lib/docker/containers
292M    /var/lib/docker/devicemapper
8.0K    /var/lib/docker/execdriver
712K    /var/lib/docker/graph
17M     /var/lib/docker/init
8.0K    /var/lib/docker/linkgraph.db
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/repositories-aufs
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/repositories-devicemapper
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/volumes
```

Could it be looking in the wrong place for it? Is there some config file that specifies the storage location?

Edit: running `docker -d -D` reports:

```
[debug] daemon.go:328 Cannot load container 93092d010a9abe9affc217684782e8b2986e560897eb4527715e9bffe0446136 because it was created with another graph driver.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [docker: how to restart containers from files from /var/lib/docker/containers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626215/docker-how-to-restart-containers-from-files-from-var-lib-docker-containers)

Comment: Could be https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4344#issuecomment-663359779

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you have somehow switched storage backends. You can't use containers created with a different backend.

Comment: Yes, that became clearer when I ran the docker server with debug output (`docker -d -D`). It turned out I had completely uninstalled all storage backends by running `apt-get dist-upgrade`. I guess the docker package in Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't correctly list its graph driver as a dependency. Reinstalling the docker package fixed the problem with no data loss.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem on Windows. I had to go to Docker-->settings-->switch to windows based container. I don't know why but somehow after reboot docker started on Linux based container. so i did not got any image and container after restart.